# vba replacement with variable sources

Tags: vba, excel

Have to replace several different links in over 800 long html codes with specific new links. 
Got an Excel sheet with old links in column A and new links in column B.
My intention is to create a user form with an input field and output field. My aim is a macro which replaces every old link with the specific new one. I can do it with one single link but not with a list of at about 350 different ones.
I got

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim varInput As String
Dim varOutput As String
varInput = tbInput
varOutput = Replace(varInput, "oldLink.intern/a1b2c3", "newLink.intern/z9y8x7")
tbOutput = varOutput
End
```

where 'tbInput' is my 1st textbox and 'tbOutput' is my 2nd one, but cant do it with my list of links

Comment: Two things:  1) You have links in Columns A & B, but are they already beside their respective counterparts?, 2) What are you thinking fro the text boxes?  If you've already a list of addresses, you could use a drop-menu (auto-complete helps).  After the drop-menu selections, you can delete the links from the source table, moving the appropriate link to a location that isn't affected by the code, as to end with one Column in in the end.

Comment: Are there any similarities between the old/new links?

Comment: m-arv thers is a couple of ways I can think about completing this task. The first way would be to `loop` down the column with the old links and find the corresponding new link using an UDF.  Another would be simply use the `findall` to replace all the old values with new link.

Comment: Cyril: 1: yes, they are beside their counterparts, 2: I have my huge HTML and wanna put it into the textbox as source for the search&replace-thing

Comment: I would use a ComboBox instead of a Textbox.  It will hold all the values and the user will get the advantage of auto complete.

Comment: Why do you want to use a userform?  You already have the old and new values.  Why not just perform a loop through those that replaces old to new?  Are the links you need to update on a different sheet?

Comment: I need a form (or anything else to put in my HTML) because my HTML is too long for an Excel cell.
The main problem is: a huge amount of long HTML documents, different links in every HTML document. I just got my old-new-link-list with links and nothing else.

I wanna my macro to
> inhale HTML
> look for link
> compare found link to link list
> if match then replace 
> recursively
> exhale new HTML

Answer (score 0):

Using a ComboBox will give you the advantage of AutoComplete.

[image]

---

```
Option Explicit
Const OLDLINK_ROOT As String = "oldLink.intern/"
Const NEWLINK_ROOT As String = "newLink.intern/"

Private Sub cboOldLink_Change()
    With cboOldLink
        If .ListIndex = -1 Then
            txtNewLink.Value = ""
        Else
            txtNewLink.Value = NEWLINK_ROOT & .list(.ListIndex, 1)
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim Column1Max As Long, Column2Max As Long, NewListWidth As Long
    With cboOldLink
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .list = getLinkList(Column1Max, Column2Max)
        .ColumnWidths = (Column1Max * .Font.Size + 1) & " pt;" & (Column2Max * .Font.Size + 1) & " pt;"
        NewListWidth = (Column1Max * .Font.Size + 1) + (Column2Max * .Font.Size + 1)
        If NewListWidth > .ListWidth Then .ListWidth = NewListWidth
    End With
End Sub

Function getLinkList(ByRef Column1Max As Long, ByRef Column2Max As Long) As Variant
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim olist As Object
    Dim key As String, item As String
    Dim list As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    Set olist = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each cell In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            key = Right(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - Len(OLDLINK_ROOT))
            item = Right(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, Len(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value) - Len(OLDLINK_ROOT))

            If Not olist.Contains(key) Then olist.Add key, item
        Next
    End With
    ReDim list(0 To olist.Count - 1, 0 To 1)

    For x = 0 To olist.Count - 1
        list(x, 0) = olist.GetKey(x)
        list(x, 1) = olist.GetByIndex(x)

        If Len(olist.GetKey(x)) > Column1Max Then Column1Max = Len(olist.GetKey(x))
        If Len(olist.GetByIndex(x)) > Column2Max Then Column2Max = Len(olist.GetByIndex(x))
    Next

    getLinkList = list
End Function
```

Comment: That's a great solution but unfortunately wont help me with my "<li>Das <strong>Anschreiben</strong> im <a href="https://oldlink.intern/x/RAlIEQ" target="_blank">Wiki</a></li><li>Vorab informier <a href="https://oldlink.intern/x/RAlIEQ" target="_blank"><strong>Diesdasjenes</strong></a><br />"-Thing because I do not wanna do that manually. Know what I mean? :)

Comment: So you are telling me that you want the user to type in `<li>Das <strong>Anschreiben</strong> im <a href="oldlink.intern/x/RAlIEQ";` to get a match?  Or would it make since to make a function that can extract the `href` from your html and another function create a link and apply the pattern that I laid out?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's as easy as that:

```
Private Sub cbMach_Click()
Dim varIn As String
Dim varOut As String
Dim i As Integer
varIn = tbIn
For i = 1 To 500
    tbIn = Replace(tbIn, Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2))
Next
tbOut = tbIn
End Sub
```

Too blind to see. Thanks guys!